# Adding or replacing a sheet in an Excel file

Tags: vba, excel, comparative-review

I have the following function and want to simplify the code to make it more readable by eliminating redundant lines:

```
Function AddSheet(shtName As String, Optional readOnlyFlag As Boolean = True) As Boolean  'Add new worksheet to current workbook at the end

    If readOnlyFlag And IsSheet(shtName) Then
        AddSheet = False
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Not readOnlyFlag Then
        If IsSheet(shtName) Then DeleteSheet (shtName)
        With ThisWorkbook:
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = shtName
        End With
        AddSheet = True
    End If

End Function
```

Since the first condition (`If readOnlyFlag And IsSheet(shtName)`) will only assign a return value of `False` to the function (which should already be the default, as I understand) and then exits the function, would it be acceptable to leave out that aspect of the logic and just have the following:

```
    If Not readOnlyFlag Then
        If IsSheet(shtName) Then DeleteSheet (shtName)
        With ThisWorkbook:
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = shtName
        End With
        AddSheet = True
    End If
```

In other words, is it best practice to be explicit like the first code block, by stating that the function returns `False` if that occurs, or to avoid what might be considered redundancy, by using the simplified second version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBA does a lot of implicit things. And it can get confusing, and it can cause surprising bugs.

Your function is implicitly `Public`. Is it meant to be called from another module? Or is it only called from within the same module it's in? Being explicit about *everything* makes the *intent* of the code much easier to understand.

The parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`, and yet, their values aren't reassigned in the body of the function (which is good!), so they could, and *should*, be passed `ByVal`. It's really a shame that `ByRef` is the implicit default in VB6/VBA.

The comment that's trailing after the function's signature, should be either immediately above, or immediately below the signature - avoid horizontal scrolling, and don't *hide* information from maintainers.

The comment could be clearer about *why* a `Boolean` return value is returned.

```
Private Function AddSheet(ByVal shtName As String, Optional ByVal readOnlyFlag As Boolean = True) As Boolean
'Appends a new worksheet to the active workbook. Returns True if sheet is successfully added.
```

It's not clear what `readOnlyFlag` does, even when reading the code. It probably could use a better name and/or a comment. It seems it determines whether the sheet should be replaced if it already exists?

The `IsSheet` function looks like it should be called `IsExistingSheetName`.

The instructions separator (colon) after `With ThisWorkbook:` serves no purpose and should be omitted; the `Exit Function` is redundant, too, since the code branches out of that block anyway.

There's an execution path where you're verifying whether the sheet name exists twice - I'd factor that check out of the `If` block.

As for the return value - I'd go even *more* explicit than that:

```
Dim result As Boolean

Dim isExisting As Boolean
isExisting = IsExistingSheetName(shtName)

If readOnlyFlag And isExisting Then
    result = False
ElseIf Not readOnlyFlag Then
    If isExisting Then DeleteSheet (shtName)
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = shtName
    End With
    result = True
End If

AddSheet = result
```

Now, how helpful is that? How does the calling code access that new worksheet now? With `Application.ActiveSheet`? That's a dangerous assumption to make!

How about returning the `Worksheet` object instead? The function would return `Nothing` if no worksheet is added, and an object reference when it is.

```
Dim result As Worksheet

Dim isExisting As Boolean
isExisting = IsExistingSheetName(shtName)

If readOnlyFlag And isExisting Then
    'Set result = Nothing '' todo: remove this useless branch
ElseIf Not readOnlyFlag Then
    If isExisting Then DeleteSheet shtName
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set result = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        If Not result Is Nothing Then result.Name = shtName
    End With
End If

Set AddSheet = result
```

Notice something? The code will blow up if `.Add` fails, because the function will return `Nothing` and then `.Name` cannot be set: you need to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive response. That's exactly what I wondered. I definitely need to be more careful with `ByRef`/`ByVal` statements. I also agree the default is out of whack. That makes me wonder, since objects are passed `ByRef`, if I pass `ThisWorkbook` to a function by reference, then in the function, reassign its value, what would happen there?

Comment: I would expect a boom ;-)

Comment: And now I need to go try it @teepee ...

Comment: Wouldn't `ThisWorkbook` be implicit to the module?

Comment: @Raystafarian implicit to the *project*, yeah. I think any function/procedure/method that needs to work with a `Workbook` object, should take that workbook as a parameter - let the caller decide whether to work against `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug no boom now, boom later.  There's always a boom